# JDK Installation: /passive switch Unattended Mode

Tags: java, java-8

JDK 7 used to have the /passive switch along with a /quiet switch. If I install with the command line with the /? switch describes the former as "Unattended mode - progress bar only"

Couple of things with JDK 8:

1. The help switch "/?" doesn't appear to be valid. Also tried "/help". Is there no help for the jdk 8 CLI installer?
2. The passive switch isn't available either. Is there a comparable switch for unattended mode?

I've tried:

jdk-7u51-windows-x64 (/passive, /?, work)

jdk-8u20-windows-x64 - passive/help switches do not work.

Comment: Probably changed. Here is the  [Documentation for JRE 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_installer_options.html)

Comment: Saw that - not a lot of information on command line options - other than the /s (silent). Surprising that they took away the help feature.